# passwords and usernames in properties file

Tags: jsp, security, properties-file

I am creating a dynamic web project in Eclipse, using JSPs and java classes. I have a .properties file with secure usernames and passwords that I want to use on my web page, these codes need to be very secure. What is the best/easiest/simplest way to accomplish this? I've read other articles, but I don't know how secure the answers are. It'd be nice to stay away from downloading/importing more files.

Comment: Just save the .prooerties file via a CipherOutputStream, and load it via a CipherInputStream. But really this always comes down to physical security of the server.

Comment: @EJP could you provide a link or some code with something that has been proven to work?